# How to catch a signal from server running in a QThread

Tags: python, server, pyqt, thread-safety, qthread

I have 2 classes:

- A *server*
- A **dummy class**

I need to be able to run this from a program like Blender. Since the *server* needs to constantly listen for any requests, I need to run it in a separate thread because otherwise it would block the main UI. The **dummy** needs to run in the main thread.

When the *server* gets a request, it needs to emit a signal that will be caught by the **dummy**. However, no matter what I try, I can't seem to catch the signal coming from the *server*.

Here is some example code that can be run without Blender:

*server* and **dummy** classes

```py
import wsgiref.simple_server
import json
from PySide2.QtCore import *

class DummyClass(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DummyClass, self).__init__()
        print("Started the dummy")

    def catch_dummy_signal(self, name, dictionary):
        print(name)
        print(dictionary)
        print("I CAUGHT THE DUMMY SIGNAL")


class Server(QObject):
    DUMMY_SIGNAL = Signal(str, dict)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()

    def start_listening(self):
        simple_server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server("127.0.0.1", 65500, self.process_request)
        print(simple_server.server_address)
        while True:
            simple_server.handle_request()

    def process_request(self, environ, start_response):
        print("Got request")
        status = "200 OK"
        headers = [("Content-type", "text/plain")]
        start_response(status, headers)
        request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
        request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
        query = json.loads(request_body)

        print("Emitting dummy signal")
        self.DUMMY_SIGNAL.emit("Luke Skywalker", {"occupation": "Jedi Knight"})

        command_result = {"query": query}
        return [json.dumps(command_result).encode()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
    dummy = DummyClass()

    server.DUMMY_SIGNAL.connect(dummy.catch_dummy_signal)

    thread = QThread()
    server.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(server.start_listening)
    thread.start()


    # running an endless loop here, otherwise the program ends. This endless loop will not be used when running it inside a program like Blender
    while True:
        pass
```

This client code can be used call make a request to the server that emits the DUMMY_SIGNAL for the **dummy** to catch:

```py
import requests
url = "http://127.0.0.1:65500"
payload = {"data": "This is important data!"}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()
print(response)
```

The output from the *server* looks like this:

```
Started the dummy
('127.0.0.1', 65500)
got request
Emitting dummy signal
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Oct/2020 16:19:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 46
```

The output from the client looks like this:

```
{'query': {'data': 'This is important data!'}}
```

As you can see from the output of the server, the print statements from `catch_dummy_signal` aren't shown. So I have to assume that the function is never called.

How do I get the `catch_dummy_signal` to fire by making a request to the *server*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals only work if there is a Qt eventloop since it is the means of transport, in your case it is enough to use a QCoreApplication:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QCoreApplication([])
    server = Server()
    dummy = DummyClass()

    server.DUMMY_SIGNAL.connect(dummy.catch_dummy_signal)

    thread = QThread()
    server.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(server.start_listening)
    thread.start()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer does indeed solve the problem as I've described it here. However, this code needs to run in Blender, which will also block if you run this as a QApp. But that's my fault on how I phrased the question :)

So I'll have to go down that particular rabbit hole to see how I can get it working when running in a "host program".